# 'ASCII' encoding inside Jupyter notebook causing a BrokenFileSystemWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, werkzeug

I started making a **python3 werkzeug web application** that is run from a linux server but every time I try to launch it from a Jupyter notebook, it displays this warning ( causing a **500 Internal Server Error** in the browser )

```
from sys import getfilesystemencoding
print(getfilesystemencoding())  # Returns 'ascii' inside Jupyter

df = DataFrame(data=......mydata......)
webservice_test = WebService(lambda: globals(), 'df', host='XXX', port=XXX)

webservice_test.start()

/home/python/anaconda3/envs/notebook_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/filesystem.py:63: BrokenFilesystemWarning: Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem: Will use UTF-8 as filesystem encoding instead of 'ascii'
  BrokenFilesystemWarning)
```

I tried disabling the warning but the web view breaks anyways ( the only difference is the warning is not displayed in Jupyter ). I found the encoding
using the **sys.getfilesystemencoding()**, which returns 'ascii' every time it is run from Jupyter, but returns 'utf-8' when it is run on the same machine outside of Jupyter.

**tl;dl
Is there any way to change default encoding inside a Jupyter notebook?**

Comment: Btw, I tried some suggestions on the original wiki and other stackoverflow threads but nothing helped.

Comment: I never used Jupyter notebook before, I only have one suggestion. Try to declare the encoding of your source file using this expression in the (first) line in your Python file: `# -*- coding: encoding -*-` where encoding is the desired encoding.

Comment: I tried # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- but it seems to have no effect on the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a few hours, I found out that one function that should return formatted html returned a **None Type**, which is not encodable in utf-8, this caused the encoding error. The main problem was Werkzeug **didn't specify on what line the error was**.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the `BrokenFilesystemWarning: Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem` error too. After digging the code, I saw that this error is harmless and just a warning in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/filesystem.py`:

```
        warnings.warn(
            'Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem: Will use UTF-8 as '
            'filesystem encoding instead of {0!r}'.format(rv),
            BrokenFilesystemWarning)
```

So, I would not worry about the `BrokenFilesystemWarning: Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem` warning.